# Calculating Damage Flux

Tags: java

So I am trying to write a program to simulate damage calculations and one portion that I am struggling to code is a gun's ammo damage stability.

Example: Gun does x damage per bullet, however, each bullet has a damage stability of 20%, so each shot can possibly do 80% of X for its hit to 120% damage. I am inputting the values of the attack, ammo count, and stability because none of them are hard set values. Right now, I am trying to figure out how to get that flux to work properly.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

```
Button runButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        runButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                damage = 0;
                damageRaw = 0;
                minuteDamage = 0;
                minuteDamageRaw = 0;
                attack = Integer.valueOf(attackBox.getText());
                cooldown = Float.valueOf(cooldownBox.getText());
                ammo = Integer.valueOf(ammoBox.getText());
                stability = Integer.valueOf(stabilityBox.getText());
                attacksPerMinute = 60 / cooldown;

                damageRaw = attack * ammo;
                minuteDamageRaw = damageRaw * (int)attacksPerMinute;
                rawDamageLabel.setText(damageRaw + " damage " + (int)attacksPerMinute + " times for a total of " + minuteDamageRaw + " damage per minute.");

                float flux = stability/100;
                for (int i = 0; i < attacksPerMinute; ++i) {
                    damage = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < ammo; ++j) {
                        damage += 1; //filler
                    }
                    minuteDamage += damage;
                }
                stabilityDamageLabel.setText(damage + " damage " + (int)attacksPerMinute + " times for a total of " + minuteDamage + " damage per minute.");
            }
        });
        runButton.setBounds(349, 10, 75, 25);
        runButton.setText("Open Fire!");
```

Comment: This is pretty broad and vague. Show an [mcve] of the code you have so far, and show what specifically you need help with. This seems like just a math problem superficially.

Comment: I edited in the code I am currently using, and its in the J for loop where I am using it. Reading a bit more, I can see potential use of Random for it, but I am struggling on how it should be implemented.